# Android MapBox SDK get fillLayer from GPS position

Tags: android, sdk, gps, mapbox, geojson

Is there a way to get the fillLayer added in mapboxMap from a GPS Position?

I have a map with many fillLayer from geoJsonSource, each of them has a value property. I want to know in wich fillLayer the device is geographically so I can tell the user what is the valueof the current place.

[image: Each color represent the value I want to get from GPS position]
Each color represent the value I want to get from GPS position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`QueryRenderedFeature()`](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/api/4.2.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMap.html#queryRenderedFeatures-android.graphics.PointF-java.lang.String...-) to query a position and from that layer and then get the geojson property. An example doing this would be:

```
final PointF pixel = mapboxMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(point);
List<Feature> features = mapboxMap.queryRenderedFeatures(pixel, "my-layer");
```

Now you should be able to grab the properties from the `Feature` object.

Comment: Thank you! I did found the function "queryRenderedFeatures" but didn't understood the parameter and what ID to put into.
It works now :)